# Telegram Weird Server names

Tags: proxy, telegram, mtproto

I am from Iran. All Mtproto proxies have been banned by the GWF (the great firewall) and It's impossible to use them, although somehow someone made a weird Mtproto proxy with even weirder server name!
The Server name: `cloudflare.com.nokia.com.co.uk.do_yo.want_to.clash_with.this.www.microsoft.com.there_is_no.place_like.localhost.www.bing.com.count_with_me.cyou.com.now_sudo.rm_rf.ddns.net.we_are_here.again_to_fight.everyone.i_am.the_internet.special_nbvd.koromozom.cfd.`

It is the only way that we can access Telegram. Does anyone know how to make such proxies with this kind of Domain?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvYNb.png)

As you can see on the attached image, It is written unknown in the server name box, but when you connect to the proxy, you will see the following domain name.
Please help to create such proxies. I really need this.